# Exception in reading file in Android code

Tags: java, android, file, file-handling

[image: No Assests Folder in Herarichy][image: Location of the file]I have a file "myFile.txt" in assets folder of my android project and I am trying to read the text of it in my android code that is shown below:

```
    String filename= "myFile.txt";

    InputStream inputStream;

    try {

        inputStream = getAssets().open(filename) ;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String text = br.readLine();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        tw.setText(text);
        br.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The application do not crash although it shows the toast in the catch block having text "myFile.txt". Help me. Waiting.

Comment: lame exception handling is worse than no exception handling and crash. Why you commented out `printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Please post the logcat displayed by e.printStackTrace().

Comment: 11-03 15:13:59.348    4443-4443/com.softMasters.filehandling W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: myFile.txt

Comment: It is not finding the file but file is available at FileHandling/build/assets

Comment: I wrote this code referring http://sree.cc/google/reading-text-file-from-assets-folder-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error is saying, Android can't find the file you're telling him to look for.
You should very firstly verify if the file is here (and not, for example, in `assets/txt`, nor in `/build/assets/`).

```
MainProjectFolder
|--> res
|--> src
|--> assets
    |--> yourFile.txt
```

Then access to its content in this way:

```
    String everything = "";

    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is = am.open(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

    TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    tw.setText(everything);
```

Comment: I have attached screen short as well of file location. Your code is also not working. Same Problem. waiting for your help. Thanks

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad as already said in my answer, you should not put your file in `/build/assets`, but only in `assets` folder. Hierarchically, your `assets` folder has to be in the same directory of `res` and `src`, do be precise. I edited my answer, please look at it.

Comment: I got you but there is no Assets folder in the main project directory. You can see the project hierarchy in my edited question. I also tried to create an assets folder in main project directory and placed file in that but it did not worked as well.. Waiting Thanks.

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad since you're using Studio (you should have specified it), your have to *create* it in this way: `src/main/assets/`. Just right click on your `main` folder and then `new > directory`. Call it assets, and put your file there.